# Tracking table changes in a log table in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am looking for a way to create a log table of a table to keep track of its changes. Let's say I have a customer table with the following format:

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_number | zipcode
1  | bob        | smith     | 000-123-4567 | 88888
```

Now the customer gets married, and decides to change their last name and move, with the new row looking like this:

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_number | zipcode
1  | bob        | williams  | 000-123-4567 | 88810
```

Is there a way for me to create a log table in this format that updates daily:

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_number | zipcode | update_date | field_changed
1  | bob        | williams  | 000-123-4567 | 88888   | 4/16/2022   | last_name          
1  | bob        | williams  | 000-123-4567 | 88810   | 4/16/2022   | zipcode
```

If a customer makes no changes, they would have no new rows added to the log table.

I am able to get the affected rows with the following query:

```
with differences as (
    select
        a.id,
        a.first_name,
        a.last_name,
        a.zip,
        a.phone,
        b.first_name,
        b.last_name,
        b.zip,
        b.phone,
        max(b.update_date) as latest_update
    from 
        customer a
    left join 
        customer_log b
    on 
        a.id = b.id and (
        a.first_name != b.first_name or
        a.last_name != b.last_name or
        a.phone != b.phone or
        a.zip != b.zip)
    where 
        b.id is not null
    group by
        a.id,
        a.first_name,
        a.last_name,
        a.zip,
        a.phone,
        b.first_name,
        b.last_name,
        b.zip,
        b.phone
)
select * from differences
```

But I am not too sure how to continue from here

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is available by take a daily copy from the live table and create new table holding the original table name+ dailt date :
for example table name is master so upon daily copy the daily one will be named master_18_14_2022
master_19_14_2022
By this you can apply a compare between the the needed tables .

Comment: This would not work, if a customer makes no changes, no rows would be added to the log table - I will add that to my question but thank you for the reply!

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? It's just a matter of writing the correct query to capture the correct data. Is a daily capture sufficient? i.e. if the person changes data three times in a day, do you need to capture all those changes, or is the last change sufficient?

Comment: It's a daily update, so essentially I am looking to capture a snapshot of the row at the end of the day and IF there are any changes, add a row to the log table with the change. So if two fields changed then it would add 2 rows for that one individual - However saving table is not an option unfortunately (for my use case)